# Visual Studio for the Hobby Developer

Tags: visual-studio

I have Visual Studio 2010 on my work machine, but I'd also like to use Visual Studio on my personal computer.  I love how Microsoft puts out a SQL Server Developer Edition, which is basically Enterprise functionality for the developer (and licensing is only allowed for developing/demo-ing).

Is there something similar for Visual Studio?  In other words, I don't want to have to pay $1000+ to be able to have Visual Studio on my personal computer for personal projects.  What's the best way to go about this?

(I'm currently using Visual C# Express and Visual Web Developer, but I would much prefer using the full version of Visual Studio on my personal projects)

Comment: Not really a programming question! But you can get Visual Studio pretty cheap, full version, via BizSpark, if your personal machine is also used for your "start-up" company according to BizSpark's rules.

Comment: @WarrenP, that looks pretty promising.  When you say "cheap", what exactly are we talking about?  Less than $100?  Doesn't look like they advertise the price, or at least without registering first..?

Comment: BizSpark is free for a period of time, I believe, if you qualify.  Not sure. Read up at the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd speak to your IT guys and see if you can get a license to "work from home". There's nothing which quite compares to visual studio...

Answer (score 0):

Are you taking any classes?  If you are even just a part time student Microsoft will give you a lot of software for free:
http://www.microsoft.com/bizspark/

Comment: I wish.  Unfortunately I am far removed from the instituted education scene.  Definitely a great option for students though.